# What if I want a certificate, but DON'T want my domain in a Certificate Transparency log?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

Say I want to get a certificate for my domain, and say that I **don't** want this to result in the name of my domain appearing in certificate transparency logs or similar locations.  (The domain is only for my personal use, and I neither need nor want to advertise it to the whole world.)

What are my options? Do most providers generally submit certificates to transparency logs?
Or do all domains that end up getting SSL/TLS certificates automatically end up on such logs?

I would use a self-signed certificate, but that won't work, because I need to use a third-party service and it needs to be able to authenticate my domain.

Ideally they would be cheap like Let's Encrypt, but I don't even know what my options are.

(Yes, I'm aware DNS logs exist regardless, and I know obscurity isn't security, etc. *That's not the point of my question*, so please refrain from offering advice on that...)

Comment: If the domain is for your personal use what about using a self-signed cert and importing it in your device's trust stores?

Comment: @AndréBorie: Doesn't work, I need to use a third-party service and it needs to be able to authenticate my domain.

Comment: You have very aggressively said what you don't want but you haven't explained why you think you need what you want. I think you would get much better answers if you explained a bit better.

Comment: @JulianKnight: Does my last comment not explain it? Like I said, I'm trying to use a third party service on my domain. Said party only provides its service over HTTPS and only to the root (no way to specify paths, etc.), so I need a verifiable certificate. But it's a personal domain and nobody else needs to know that it exists. I don't want to get a new domain name just because of this, and regardless, I would still have to advertise that which I prefer not to do if I don't need to. If it's impossible to do what I'm asking then that's a valid answer. I think this should be clear?

Comment: In that case, you can possibly redirect your domain through Cloudflare. Use their HTTPS service which delivers valid certs for any domain used via them. Use your self-signed cert to secure the connection between your server and Cloudflare and make sure that you restrict access to your server so only CF connections will make it through.

Comment: @JulianKnight: That's really interesting. So are you saying that that would be less prone to spreading my domain name than obtaining a certificate from any CA? Are there really no CAs that are known to avoid submitting domains to third parties? I almost feel like I might avoid transparency logs here, but end up on a bunch of other logs instead, but I have no idea how CloudFlare works in this respect.

Comment: The problem is that the whole point of the web is to expose domains to discovery. The only way to avoid that is to only use IP addresses but that would take you back to using self-signed certs only. I don't think you can really do what you want as you want it. I'm only guessing really that CF would leave less of a footprint than your own registered cert.

Comment: @JulianKnight: I mean, it was kind of possible before they started doing this certificate transparency thing, so it's not like it fundamentally goes against what the internet is. But if it's no longer possible then that's unfortunate... thanks for the suggestion anyhow.

Comment: Some ISPs assign a default domain name (which is also the reverse DNS) to their connections - you could get a cert for that name (which is unrelated to your identity) and then use it to host a proxy to your actual, private domain.

Comment: @AndréBorie: Thanks for the idea, I might try that!

Comment: @Mehrdad give it a try. Some virtual server providers are pretty cheap at 10$/month like Linode or Digital Ocean.

Comment: FYI: Google has a [*plan to require CT in October 2017*](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/tgn5R-58iek). (Not sure if they have decided on privacy options yet.)

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff: Good to know, thanks for the heads up! Seems it's only a Chrome thing though, so it wouldn't really matter for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for a subdomain is a wildcard certificate:

To protect secretdomain.example.com, get a *.example.com certificate. But it's expensive. The wildcard could be submitted to ct logs, but it will not reveal the real domain name.

The two other solution are:

- using a CA that don't sumbit certificates to ct logs, but anybody visiting your website could submit your certificate. (some bots crawl the web do to it)
- using a CA that submit to ct logs with name redaction, but browsers do not yet understant it, it's at your own risk.

Another possibility is to transform **secretdomain.com** to **notsecretdomain.com/secretdomain**: with that you avoir ct logs, DNS logs, and even https leaks (when using https, the path is protected, but not the domain)

Comment: The first thing you mentioned is a brilliant idea, except here the issue here is I don't want the second level domain in the logs either (in fact the third level one is benign). For the other two solutions, which CAs don't submit to such logs? I have no idea how to even find out, that's kind of why I asked this question. And regarding the last solution, it doesn't work since I need a third party service to be able to verify my domain.

Comment: "Which CQs don't submit themselves to CT logs" is another (good) question. You should ask it. And for information: "Certificate Transparency Will Be Mandatory in Chrome" https://securityintelligence.com/news/certificate-transparency-will-be-mandatory-in-chrome/ so any answer will only be valid until that... Another point: is that domain is only for your private use, maybe you could use a self signed certificate?

Comment: Regarding self-signed, see my earlier comment on my question. And I'm not looking for a list of CAs necessarily, that's just one particular way to answer the question. You could also just tell me how to figure it out myself or something. Figuring out how to go about this was the purpose of this question, so it's kind of defeating the purpose for me to ask another one.